# How to sequentially execute functions in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, promise, sequential-workflow

I am trying to upload images to firebase storage and then when uploads finish, execute a try/catch block of codes with addDoc() command to create a doc inside fb database. The sample coding is as follows:

```
const abc = () => {

  array.map(() => {
    return uploadFilesToFb()
  })
  
  // then, when the above function finishes
  createDocInFb()
}
```

I heard about Promises, but is there any other way of doing this? I mean, in firebase there are `.then` functions but since I have a mapping I couldn't put `addDoc()` after `.then` of `uploadFilesToFb()`. If only alternative is promises, how can I achieve that with promises?

Comment: I’d take a step back and read up on async/await, promises in general, how to handle collections of asyncs, etc. It’ll pay off quickly.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I am now looking async/await. When used, warning comes: "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression." when I used it with mapping function.

Comment: It’s not clear what you tried.